# unable to click a drop-down item with selenium chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click a drop-down item.

I am at:

I can click the proxy location option using the code below, but I can't select any items from the drop-down;

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/p")).Click();
```

how can I click the Germany or USA option from the drop-down?

I've tried this code below and it didn't work

```
var dd = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/p")).Click();
var select = new SelectElement(dd);
select.SelectByValue(" Germany");
```

Comment: Is the space before `Germany` (last line of code) intentional or an error?

Comment: U need to add relevant html. Also the xpath used are fragile to any minor UI changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
 Select dropdown = new SelectElement(driver.findelement(By.id("dropdown")));
 dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Germany"); or dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
```

Some further reading that might help:

1. [How to Select Option from DropDown using Selenium Webdriver](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiojKuwyPbZAhXOqYMKHbWMB18QFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.guru99.com%2Fselect-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html&usg=AOvVaw1hhBNiYnC9t9axswWBnO36)
2. [How to Select a Dropdown in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiojKuwyPbZAhXOqYMKHbWMB18QFgg3MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Floadfocus.com%2Fblog%2F2016%2F06%2F13%2Fhow-to-select-a-dropdown-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java%2F&usg=AOvVaw3funH5GKu4Fm5rVKDwQKPZ)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the logic used by the drop down it can be hard to provide code that will work for you. But I can tell right away that it's is not a select tag and the SelectByValue won't work on it.

This is where things get nasty and you have to use ActionChains. You have to find the child element that contains the text you want and then click on it.

```
dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/p"))
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(dropdown)
// var childSelection = // Logic to find child elements of dropdown
actions.click(childSelection).perform();
```